# Two variants of the BST remove algorithm

Tags: algorithms, binary-search-trees

I have seen two variants of the BST remove algorithm in the case where the node to be removed has both children.

**Variant 1:**
Replace the node with the right-most child in the left subtree

**Variant 2:**
Replace the node with the left-most child in the right subtree

Is there a way to establish theoretically that the two operations are equivalent?

Comment: They are not equivalent since the resulting tree could differ.

Comment: I suspect you will need to define what you mean by "equivalent".